# VirtualEnv is installed, but cannot find bin/activate

Tags: django, mercurial, virtualenv

We had a working project with git, and our instructor moved our project over to mercurial after making some changes.
I pulled the new project and started it up under a new folder.
I tried running a virtualenv for the new project but I get: `Requirement already satisfied`
I would usually then run `$ . bin/activate` but I cannot find a bin folder.

How do I get a virtualenv setup for this project at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place where you have your project isn't necessarily the place where you have the environment. Did you have the environment in git too?

Perhaps what you need to do (in case you don't have a versioned environment) is recreate the environment (*virtualenv environment*), install the dependencies (*pip install -r req.txt*) and then activate it (*source path/to/environment/bin/activate*).

Good luck.

Comment: @Benjamin, _activate_ is actually a file. You pass its path as an argument to the _source_ command. Like so: $ source ./environment/bin/activate. [Here's](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) some info on virtualenv, check out the section marked "usage". Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok

Try this an awesome link to How to install django in  virtual environment .

http://ayarshabeer.com/post/50973941605/install-multiple-django-version-using-virtualenvwrapper

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps

```
virtualenv virenv_name --no-site-packages -  create new virtual environment in git
pip install -r requirements.pip           -  It can be used for install tools in   
                                              (requirements.pip files)
yolk -l                   - It will used for list install files
source git/virenv_name/bin/activate       - Activate virtualenv
deactivate                                -  Deactivate virtualenv
```